# MySQL query optimization with compound index and persistent column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

The following query is being run on MariaDB 10.0.28, taking ~17 seconds, I'm looking to speed it up substantially.

```
select series_id,delivery_date,delivery_he,forecast_date,forecast_he,value 
from forecast where forecast_he=8 
AND series_id in (12142594,20735627,632287496,1146453088,1206342447,1154376340,2095084238,2445233529,2495523920,2541234725,2904312523,3564421486) 
AND delivery_date >= '2016-07-13' 
AND delivery_date < '2018-06-27' 
and DATEDIFF(delivery_date,forecast_date)=1
```

The first attempt to speed it up was to create a persistent column as (datediff(delivery_date,forecast_date)), rebuild the index using the persistent column, and modify the query, replacing the datediff calc with forecast_delivery_delta=1

```
> describe forecast;
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| Field                   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra      |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+
| series_id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |            |
| delivery_date           | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |            |
| delivery_he             | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |            |
| forecast_date           | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |            |
| forecast_he             | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |            |
| value                   | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |            |
| forecast_delivery_delta | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | NULL    | PERSISTENT |
+-------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+------------+

> show index from forecast;
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| forecast |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | series_id     | A         |       35081 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          0 | PRIMARY              |            2 | delivery_date | A         |      130472 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          0 | PRIMARY              |            3 | delivery_he   | A         |     1290223 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          0 | PRIMARY              |            4 | forecast_date | A         |     2322401 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          0 | PRIMARY              |            5 | forecast_he   | A         |    23224016 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          1 | he_series_delta_date |            1 | forecast_he   | A         |       29812 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          1 | he_series_delta_date |            2 | series_id     | A         |       74198 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| forecast |          1 | he_series_delta_date |            3 | delivery_date | A         |      774133 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

This seems to have taken ~2 seconds off the runtime, but I'm wondering if there are better ways to speed this up substantially. I looked into adjusting the buffer size but it seemed not to be wildly misconfigured.

```
>show variables like '%innodb_buffer_pool_size%';
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+


Total table size:
+----------+------------+
| Table    | Size in MB |
+----------+------------+
| forecast |    1547.00 |
+----------+------------+

EXPLAIN:
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys                | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | forecast | range | PRIMARY,he_series_delta_date | he_series_delta_date | 11      | NULL | 832016 | Using index condition |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: can you also post the from EXPLAIN "your query"

Comment: I've included results of EXPLAIN at the bottom of the post.

Comment: The buffer pool size is 128MB, which is not configured at all. It's the default value, meant to be usable on a laptop or minimally-sized server. It is probably not enough for any production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to say

```
AND forecast_delivery_delta=1
```

then the optimal index is one *starting* with the two `=` columns:

```
(forecast_he, forecast_delivery_delta,    -- in either order
 series_id,           -- an IN might work ok next
 delivery_date)       -- finally a range
```

It is generally useless to put a column (`delivery_date`) tested via a range anywhere other than last.

But note, that index will not work very well if you say forecast_delivery_delta <= 2.  Now it is a "range", and nothing after it in the index will be used for filtering.  Still it may be worth it to have a small number of different indexes, just in case you turn `=` into a range or vice versa.

And increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be about 70% of RAM (assuming you have over 4GB of RAM).

Comment: This brought the query time from 15 seconds to .5 seconds, without any changes to the buffer size. Really helpful, thanks Rick!

Comment: @dsclough - Learn more from my [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .